Why is the position of the minus sign inside the tikz node shifted upwards when using the unicode-math package?
I’m encountering an issue when using the unicode-math package with tikz node. When I include a minus sign in a node, it gets shifted upwards, whereas without the package, the minus sign is centered correctly.
Here’s a minimal example demonstrating the issue:
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \node [circle, draw] {$-$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

In this case, the minus sign inside the node is shifted upwards.

If I don’t use the unicode-math package, the result looks like this:
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \node [circle, draw] {$-$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


At first glance, the shift doesn't seem to be significant, but in some drawings it reaches simply catastrophic consequences. Just look at the blue negative charge.


is it really shifted of does the circle change size?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Exactly shifts, look at the charges.

The glyph has different dimensions in different fonts, you can compare \fbox{$-$} with and without the unicode-math package to see the effect. Given that the size of your node adapts to the size of the content, the minus will end up at different positions:

To avoid changing the size of the circle, you could either set a fixed size for the circle or add a \mathstrut:
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \node [circle, draw] {$\mathstrut -$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you, that's really the solution.

@sergiokapone You're welcome!

I had a similar problem in circuitikz, see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/721 - I ended up using $\vphantom{+}-$ which seems to work correctly in most fonts.

@Rmano Life would be so much easier with an Henry Ford font selection, choosing between CM and CM :)

or using picture mode \circle instead of this newfangled tikz thingy

@DavidCarlisle :)
